# Force download in IE8 using PHP headers is not working

Tags: php

I have used below code for Download a file using PHP headers, It works fine in other browsers But it is not Working in IE8. In IE8 download prompt is not displayed, and also new window automatically opened, then suddenly closed.

```
$('#download').click(function()){
  window.open('Download.php');
});
```

Download.php

```
session_start();
$file = $_SESSION['DFN'];   
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
}
```

Comment: I have called the Download.php in Ajax Success part.

Comment: Did u try to access the page directly with the browser rather than use JS to open the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($file) {

      $dir      = "../uploads/";        

    $mime_types =   array(
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
        "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
        "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
        "mpeg" => "audio/mpeg",
        "swf"=> "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "rar" =>  "application/x-rar-compressed",       
        "mp4" => "audio/mp4"
     );


    if ((isset($file))&&(file_exists($dir.$file))) {

       header("Content-type: " . $mime_types[get_file_extention($file)]);

       header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $dir.$file . '"');
       header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
       header("Content-length: ".filesize($dir.$file));
       header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');

       readfile("$dir$file");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply, But still that issue is not fixed, Can you have any idea?